# Help with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have two tables: players and cards2

In each cards2 row, there is at least one player id (pid, pid2, pid3, pid4). I'm trying to come up with a select statement to get all fname's and lname's if there is more than one player id (pid's that are not 0). There is always a pid, but not always a pid2, pid3, etc. Does this make sense?

Here are the structures.

Players table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `player_id` mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sport_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hof` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=421 ;
```

Cards2 table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cards2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  `pid2` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  `pid3` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  `pid4` mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  `num` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000',
  `notes` text,
  `new_manuf` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sportid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fname` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=572 ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of fname and lname in the cards2 table?

Comment: Mark,
There is no purpose for those in cards2 table. Those should have been removed. I was using those originally.

Comment: @Kyle thanks for your answer. Can you also clarify this please: you say that there will always be one non-zero player id in (pid, pid2, nid3, pid4) and later you say there is always a pid but not necessarily a pid2, pid3 or pid4. The second statement is stronger than the first. Which do you mean? If you mean the second, how will you handle the first player wanting to quit the game, but the remaining players wanting to continue without her?

Comment: This is actually being used to track autographs. Some autographed cards have one signature (only pid is used, therefore pid is always filled out). For multisigned cards pid is used and also pid2 and maybe pid3 and pid4 depending on how many signatures there are. Like you said before, this seems like a bad idea so I think adding another table to normalize my data seems like the best answer.

Comment: @Kyle: OK, again thanks for the clarification. +1 to the question for responding quickly to clarification requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    P1.fname AS fname1,
    P1.lname AS lname1,
    P2.fname AS fname2,
    P2.lname AS lname2,
    P3.fname AS fname3,
    P3.lname AS lname3,
    P4.fname AS fname4,
    P4.lname AS lname4
FROM cards2
LEFT JOIN players P1 ON pid = P1.player_id
LEFT JOIN players P2 ON pid2 = P2.player_id
LEFT JOIN players P3 ON pid3 = P3.player_id
LEFT JOIN players P4 ON pid4 = P4.player_id
```

You might want to consider if it is a good idea to [normalize your database](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/firstnormalform.htm) though. Having four columns for four players seems like a bad idea. What if you later want to allow 6 players?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Good point. I guess normalizing would be the best route. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider redesigning your tables if that's a possibility.  The repeating player ID's in the CARD2 table will make querying difficult and artificially limit how many players can be associated with a particular card.  If you're still in the design stage you can save yourself some grief later by redoing things now.  Here's a quick shot at it:

First, redo the 'cards2' table to eliminate the player references:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cards2` ( 
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `num` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000', 
  `notes` text, 
  `new_manuf` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
  `sportid` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
  PRIMARY KEY (`card_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=572;
```

Then create what's called a "junction table" to map the many-to-many relationship between cards and players (i.e. one player can appear on many cards, and many players can appear on one card):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'card_player' (
  'card_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'player_id' mediumint(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('card_id', 'player_id'),
  FOREIGN KEY 'card_id' REFERENCES card2.card_id,
  FOREIGN KEY player_id REFERENCES players.player_id
) ENGINE=MYISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Eliminating the repeated player_id's in the CARDS2 table should make querying easier.  For example,

```
SELECT c.card_id, p.fname, p.lname
  FROM players p,
       cards2 c,
       card_player x
  WHERE x.card_id = c.card_id AND
        p.player_id = x.player_id
  ORDER BY c.card_id;
```

This also eliminates the limitation of having at most four players associated with a particular card, so if you have a team card with 20 players on it this new set of table definitions can handle it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Makes perfect sense. I ended up going with three additional tables. Players, which holds the player id's, names.... cards_players, which holds card_id and associated player_ids, and cards2, which hold other metadata about the cards (card_id, card name, year, brand, image, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
   SELECT CONCAT(p1.fname, ' ', p1.lname) AS player1,
          CONCAT(p2.fname, ' ', p2.lname) AS player2,
          CONCAT(p3.fname, ' ', p3.lname) AS player3,
          CONCAT(p4.fname, ' ', p4.lname) AS player4,
     FROM CARDS2 c
     JOIN PLAYERS p1 ON p1.playerid = c.pid
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS p2 ON p2.playerid = c.pid2
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS p3 ON p3.playerid = c.pid3
LEFT JOIN PLAYERS p4 ON p4.playerid = c.pid4
```

Answer (score 1):

About making sense, wouldn't it be cleaner creating simple n:m players_tables_map table? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: You have a point, but this is a comment not an answer.  There are some who will downvote because of that.